# DllNotFound: FirebaseCppApp-6_14_0 on Android only?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am currently using Unity to create my game, and I am implementing the user account system now. The send/receive methods for username/password work perfectly fine in Editor, but when I build on Android, logcat gives me the error in the question title (DllNotFound).

Obviously the DLL is not missing, yes? Otherwise it wouldn't work on standalone desktop/Editor? If this is the case, I am assuming it isn't getting built into the Unity .apk for whatever reason. Does anyone have any reason why? I haven't found any useful resources online, as all the similar questions I have run across are regarding no functionality at all, not split functionality across platforms.

What reasons would Unity recognize a DLL in Editor/standalone, but not on an Android build?
(The .dll in question is located at \Assets\Firebase\Plugins\x86_64, if that helps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fix is probably to run force resolve in the Android resolver.

[image: Assets/External Dependency Manager/Android Resolver/Force Resolve]

Which should give you the file you need as part of `firebase-app-unity`:
[image: Assets/Plugins/Android expanded with firebase-app-unity highlighted]

My reasoning:

The Unity SDK actually ships with roughly five copies of each native library for iOS, Android, MacOS, Windows, and Linux (plus variants for different architectures &c). The FirebaseCppApp libraries being C++ implementations of some Firebase features. If you look in the folder you listed, you'll see a bunch of library folders for different editor platforms:

```
╰─$ ls -al | fgrep -v .meta
total 558360
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 martinpatrick  primarygroup        448 May  8 10:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 martinpatrick  primarygroup        800 May  8 10:18 ..
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 martinpatrick  primarygroup      48236 Dec  4  2016 FirebaseCppAnalytics.bundle
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 martinpatrick  primarygroup     355840 Dec  4  2016 FirebaseCppAnalytics.dll
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 martinpatrick  primarygroup     226136 Dec  4  2016 FirebaseCppAnalytics.so
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 martinpatrick  primarygroup   23186972 Dec  4  2016 FirebaseCppApp-6_14_0.bundle
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 martinpatrick  primarygroup    7526400 Dec  4  2016 FirebaseCppApp-6_14_0.dll
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 martinpatrick  primarygroup  254502608 Dec  4  2016 FirebaseCppApp-6_14_0.so
```

`bundle` is for OSX, `dll` is for Windows, and `so` is for Linux.

Clearly this is missing the iOS and Android variants of the SDKs.

The native iOS and Android packages are being pulled in via External Dependency Manager for You ([see this post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef?source=friends_link&sk=8db8be3ebd2b2e2452fb9ef440a9cf7a), Play Services Resolver is the old name). When it runs, it looks for a file matching the pattern `*Dependencies.xml` and starts looking for native libraries to pull in.

Firebase includes a local Android maven repository at `Assets/Firebase/m2repository` which contains `firebase-app-unity-6.14.0.srcaar` with the Android C++ implementation. If you're not using gradle to resolve dependencies, it should copy the necessary components into `Assets/Plugins/Android` on build depending on your settings in the resolver:
[image: Settings window]

Note that if you're using gradle, this package will be added to your `mainTemplate.gradle`. If there's no mention of it, something may have gone wrong.

--Patrick

Comment: Hey, you're the guy on all the YouTube videos!
Thanks for the response, very detailed and informative. I am currently attempting this solution, I will get back to you if something goes wrong. If not, you can assume it worked. I marked this as correct, assuming you know what you're talking about better than anyone else. Thank you for your help Patrick.

Comment: I love the trust! The pressure's on now. There's always the chance that you're seeing something I haven't.

Comment: No pressure at all Patrick, the solution worked as intended! Thank you so much, this was a huge roadblock for me and getting past it allows my app to actually function as intended. Keep up the good work on YouTube and at Firebase! Love the product so far.

Comment: I'm just glad to have helped!